# How can I tell if Elementor templates are GPL licensed or not?

Tags: gpl

I have some [Elementor](https://elementor.com/) templates but I don't know if they are GPL licensed. How can I tell which license they are under?

Comment: What templates?

Comment: Have you done your own research? https://google.com/search?q=license+site%3Aelementor.com ?
Have you looked at the subsection 'Template Library' [here](https://elementor.com/terms/) ?

Answer (score 1):

If the templates are GPL licensed, you *should* have received at a bare minimum:

- A full copy of the GPL license itself
- Either the full source code to the template, or an offer to supply the full source code to the template

If you did not receive these, then the template is under a different license (or is GPL licensed and distributed in violation of the GPL).

Comment: Or it's distributed by the sole rightsholders, who (not being bound by their choice of the GPL) are free to ignore the requirement to distribute a copy of the GPL (or, indeed, the source, though that would be actively perverse).  Since this happens depressingly often, I note that the absence of a copy of the licence can't be used as a reliable indicator of GPL status.

Comment: Agreed, if the two bullet points above are fulfilled you can be pretty sure it _is_ GPL licensed but their absence doesn't prove it is not GPL licensed.

Comment: Well put, completely agree!